I keep getting "Import "solders.keypair" could not be resolved from source" when trying to import Keypair from solders.keypair. Why?
As the title states I keep getting "Import "solders.keypair" could not be resolved from source" error when importing solders.keypair.
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.keypair import Keypair

I've installed solders... even uninstalled and re-installed, but still getting the error. I have python 3.12 downloaded is that the problem, if so how do i downgrade version. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Are you able to run your code or you get this error while executing? I had a similar issue but it was a warning and I fixed it by ignoring type warnings from solders.keypair import Keypair # type: ignore.
